# Why does Intellisense not work for Default Public Property (sometimes)?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, intellisense

I've had problems with default properties in my code that I can - at least to some extent - reproduce with the following code:

```
Public Class Dawg
    Public Enum DawgEnum
        Demo1
        Demo2
    End Enum
    Default Public Property DawgProp(x As DawgEnum) As String
        Get
            Return "whatever"
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            '...
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Sub DawgSub()
        Me(DawgEnum.Demo1) = "Intellisense works here..."
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class DawgTest
    Public Sub SomeSub()
        Dim d As New Dawg
        d(Dawg.DawgEnum.Demo1) = "And here as well..."

    End Sub

    Public Shared Sub AnotherSub()
        Dim d As New Dawg

        d(Dawg.DawgEnum.Demo1) = "No help for finding 'Dawg.DawgEnum.Demo1' here..."

        d.DawgProp(Dawg.DawgEnum.Demo1) = "...Intellisense helped here..."

    End Sub
End Class
```

The problem being that within the "**Shared** Sub AnotherSub" when I start typing "d(" Intellisense does not offer me the list of available Enum values for the property.

I also have the problem in other classes that structurally are identical to the class "DawgTest" (a simple public class) where it doesn't work either (within a shared sub or not) - although there are no problems in the test above.

Of course, this isn't a major problem since the code compiles fine and I can always use the explicit property, but it's very annoying and confusing and just like to know, if this is by-design? And, if so: why? If not: how can I fix it?

I can't for sure say, if this problem has been there all along or, if it just came up out of nowhere...

Any thoughts - even 5 cents or less - on the issue would be greatly appreciated :o)

Comment: If that's the only trouble that you've had with Visual Studio and, in particular, intellisense, then consider yourself lucky :)

Comment: Will intellisense work at all if you hit CTRL+Space? (Or whichever your 'show intellisense' is bound to).   Intellisense is remarkably finicky.  Sometimes it clears up with a clean/rebuild, or exit/delete .suo file/reopen project/rebuild

Comment: Clearly this is a bug, we cannot fix it for you.  Post this to connect.microsoft.com

Comment: Yeah, reproducible bug.  Same in VB 2013 Pro.